# How to prove $f'(\xi)=a$ ,if $ f(0)=0,f(a)=a,f'(x_{0})=0$?

Tags: analysis

let $a\in (0,1)$,and $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,a]$, and is 
differentiable on $(0,a)$, and $x_{0}\in (0,a)$,such $f'(x_{0})=0$,and 
such
$$f(0)=0, f(a)=a$$
show that
there exsit $\xi\in(0,a)$,such
$$f'(\xi)=a$$

My try: I want to put
$$F(x)=f(x)-ax$$
since
$$F(0)=f(0)-0=0$$
so
if we find another point $c\in(0,a)$ such that $F(c)=f(c)-ac$

then we can use Rolle theorem to prove it.

Now How to prove there exist $c\in(0,a)$,such that $f(c)=ac$

maybe this method is not useful,Thank you.

Comment: By MVT there exists $x_1\in (0,a)$ such that $f'(x_1)=\frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a-0}=1$. So $f'$ takes the values $0$ and $1$. By [Darboux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)), it also takes the value $a\in (0,1)$. Now surely this is overkill...

Comment: It's time to take efforts in English learning...

Comment: @CWeid [Did you mean](http://www.italki.com/question/189202): "It's time to make efforts to learn English"? Or can we really say "to take efforts in doing something"?

Comment: @julien Oops.My fault.Thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

using Rolle theorem   you obtain

$\exists c \in (0,1)\qquad F'(c)=0$

$F'(x)=f'(x)-a$

$F'(c)=f'(c)-a=0$
Finally

$f'(c)=a$

Comment: why $F'(c)=0?$,I think we can't have this

Comment: My mistake. I thought that $F(a)=0$, but it isn't.